# Is crystal report for visual studio 2013 free?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crystal-reports, reporting

I just need to generate basic reports with random parameters passed from asp.net c# code to the report.

I have searched a lot of pages even lots of people on stackoverflow have different opinions. But I need to clear this for my enterprise level project.
Is SAP Crystal Report for visual studio 2013 developer version free to use at development time as well as at deployment.

I have downloaded this from the following link:

```
http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_15.exe
```

Please help with authentic proves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the licensing that they have posted, yes it is free. Here is a link to the SAP forums that talks about it. http://scn.sap.com/thread/3462449

Comment: Does it mean that I can **deploy** my **distributed** application with basic crystal reporting for free?

Comment: That is how I interpreted it.  I did see a note somewhere that they have a restriction for server applications that allow for multiple concurrent user connections, but I don't know what your app is and the comment was for an older version of CR.

Comment: My app is a distributed application which will work in an intranet environment. And i dont need any data analysis tools to work with. I just want plain simple reports which I can proceed to print. So based on my such simple requirements, will it be free of cost in a distributed client server environment ?

Comment: The way I interpret their licensing, I would say that yes it is within the allowed uses for the free license.